# Prove that intersection of complement of event A with union of event B and C complement are independent

Tags: probability, probability-theory, independence

I am trying to see if the following holds: if $A,B,C$ are independent so is $P(A^c\cap (B\cup C^c)) $.

I wanted to do a proof by contradiction so I started by assuming that this holds and tried to find if it does not necessarily hold.

\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
P(A^c\cap (B\cup C^c)) & = P(A^c)P(B\cup C^c)\\
 & = [1- P(A)] [P(B) + 1-P(C) -P(B)(1-P(C)]\\
 & = [1- P(A)] [ 1-P(C) -P(B)P(C)]\\
 & = [1-P(A)][1-P(C)(1-P(B))]
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

Now I tried to expand this expression hoping that something will cancel out but it resulted just in the expression:

\begin{equation}
1-P(A)-P(C)-P(A)P(C)-P(B)P(C)-P(A)P(B)P(C)
\end{equation}
Which does not look like any definition of independence I ever saw. But then I know that all individual terms of that expression are independent and if I subtract just a bunch of independent events from the event space (1) it feels like the results should be independent too.

Comment: Your first line does not make any sense.

Comment: @user52227 but that is just and assumption I am trying to prove wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't know by contradiction (note that if you want to prove it by contradiction, then you should instead start by assuming that they are NOT independent), but note that:
\begin{align}
P(A^c \cap  (B\cup C^c))
& = P(A^c \cap B ) + P(A^c \cap  C^c) - P(A^c \cap  B\cap C^c) \\
& = P(A^c)P(B ) + P(A^c)P(C^c) - P(A^c)P( B)P( C^c) \\
& = P(A^c) ( P(B ) +  P(C^c) - P( B)P( C^c)) \\
& = P(A^c)  P( B\cup C^c ) 
\end{align}
where in the second equality I used the independence of $A,B$, and $C$, otherwise the well known formula for the probability of the union of two events.

Comment: oh okay now I see what you meant. I did not realize that this can be written out like this and I just wrote out the first part and second part separately.